# Parsing the xml file to create hyperlinks

Tags: python

1.I am trying to read an xml file between the tags "sanity_results"( look at for the input http://pastebin.com/p9H8GQt4) and print the output

2.for any line or part of line that has http:// or // I want it to append "a href" hyperlink tag to the link so that when I post to email they appear as hyperlinks in the email

```
Input file(results.xml)
http://pastebin.com/p9H8GQt4


def getsanityresults(xmlfile):
    srstart=xmlfile.find('<Sanity_Results>')
    srend=xmlfile.find('</Sanity_Results>')
    sanity_results=xmlfile[srstart+16:srend].strip()
    sanity_results = sanity_results.replace('\n','<br>\n')
    return sanity_results

def main ():
xmlfile = open('results.xml','r')
contents = xmlfile.read()
testresults=getsanityresults(contents)
print testresults
for line in testresults:
        line = line.strip()
        //How to find if the line contains "http" or "\\" or "//" and append "a href"attribute
        resultslis.append(link)
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    main()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at your error message:

```
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'find'
```

And then have a look at `main()`: you're feeding the result of `open('results.xml', 'r')` into `getsanityresults`. But `open(...)` returns a *file object*, whereas `getsanityresults` expects `xmlfile` to be a *string*.

You need to extract the *contents* of `xmlfile` and feed that inti `getsanityresults`.

To get the contents of a file, read [this bit of the python documentation]9http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

In particular, try:

```
xmlfile = open('results.xml', 'r')
contents = xmlfile.read() # <-- this is a string
testresults = getsanityresults(contents) # <-- feed a string into getsanityresults
# ... rest of code
```

Comment: coffee - Thanks,my issue#2,how to find if the line contains "http" or "\\" or "//" and append "a href"attribute

Comment: It's probably best that you ask about separate issues in separate questions. If each link is on its own line, you can use [string.find](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) to see if `http://` or `\\` is present in the line, and if so, surround it with `<a href="..."></a>`.