# Find http or // or \\ in a string and surround with a href atribute

Tags: python

I am trying to find a link which contains http or // or \ and surround with a href tag once its found,does anyone have any ideas on how this can be done

```
 INput:-http://pastebin.com/p9H8GQt4

sanity_results = sanity_results.replace('\n','<br>\n')
return sanity_results

def main ():
resultslis=[]
xmlfile = open('results.xml','r')
contents = xmlfile.read()
testresults=getsanityresults(contents)
#print testresults
for line in testresults:
    #print line
    line = line.strip()
    #print line
    line = re.sub(r'(http://[^\s]+|//[^\s]+|\\\\[^\s]+)', r'<a href="\1">\1</a>', line)
    print line       
    resultslis.append(line)
print resultslis

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Comment: Your indentation is screwed up. I'll take a guess at how to fix it, but please look it over and make sure I got it right (and, in the future, paste things properly).

Comment: [Related question with link to the data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464962/parsing-the-xml-file-to-create-hyperlinks) (I asked the OP to split their two questions into two parts, this is the second part).

Comment: Are the links going to be an entire line (after stripping)? If not, how are they delimited? If you're trying to auto-link in plain text, the rules can get pretty tricky: http://example.com, http://example.com? http://example.com?var=val.

Comment: You've replaced your original code with a completely different implementation, which makes the question and its answers much less useful to anyone searching for it. Also, your new version again has broken indentation, and seems to be missing at least one line, and has at least one extra line that's not part of the code. You really need to post your actual code in a form that can be read and/or run by other people if you want people to debug it. Also, you haven't explained what the problem is with your new version, so what exactly are you asking?

Comment: … But all that being said, I can immediately see a problem here. `contents` is a big string that you get from `xmlfile.read()`. Then `testresults` is something that you get from processing that string, so presumably it's a big string too. Then you do `for line in testresults:`. Since `testresults` is a string rather than a sequence of strings, this will loop over the characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for this:

```
line = re.sub(r'(http://[^\s]+)', r'<a href>\1</a>', line)
```

That just handles the `http://` case. To handle all three, just do this:

```
line = re.sub(r'(http://[^\s]+|//[^\s]+|\\\\[^\s]+)', r'<a href>\1</a>', line)
```

Play with that regexp in the console to make sure it does what you want, but it seems to do what you asked for with [your posted input data](http://pastebin.com/p9H8GQt4). As I mentioned in a comment, in general, you need to figure out what delimiters can end a link if you want to auto-link text.

Meanwhile, are you sure the problem spec is correct? Normally, you don't want this:

```
<a href>http://foo/bar</a>
```

… but this:

```
<a href="http://foo/bar">http://foo/bar</a>
```

To get that, just change the `sub` replacement expression to `r'<a href="\1">\1</a>'`.

You could also write the whole thing with string functions, but for anything but simple cases, that actually turns out to be a lot harder than learning regexps. For example, the equivalent of the above one-liner is something like this:

```
index = 0
while index is not None:
    index = min(line.find(pattern, index) for pattern in ('http:', '//', '\\\\'))
    if index == -1:
        break
    space = line.find(' ', index)
    if space == -1:
        space = None
    line = line[:index] + '<a href>' + line[index:space] + '</a>' + line[space:]
    index = space
```

Except that I'm willing to bet I've got at least one obvious fencepost error in there, and likely at least one subtle bug with possible overlapping patterns, and so on.

Comment: I tried it but I am not getting the desired output for the input provided above..every letter is getting stripped.and output lis lik ['8', '9', '6', '0', ':', '<', 'b', 'r', '>', '', '', '', '', '', '\\',.....

Comment: @user1795998: Your problem is obviously that you're iterating over a string instead of a list of strings. This means either that you're doing something like `for line in f.read():` instead of `for line in f:`, or you've accidentally put in two loops like `for thingy in f:` then `for line in thingy:`.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation on [string escape sequences](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) and [string operations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html).

```
if (line.find('http') != -1 or line.find('\\\\') != -1 or line.find('//') != -1):
    line = '<a href="">'+line+'</a>'
```

Comment: This will surround the whole line in an `href` tag, not just the link.

Comment: He posted a link to the example data at some point - his data is such that the each link is completely on its own line so this will work for that.

Comment: Looking at the link from the other question (http://pastebin.com/p9H8GQt4) that doesn't see to be true. For example, at line 11, there's `8960: http://ajm/ATMWebApp/JobRunResults/Default.aspx?JobRunID=8509752`.